# Command prompt won't recognize python

Tags: python-3.x, komodo

Hope this is not off topic. I recently installed the Komodo editor and now, when I try to run a script from my command prompt, it no longer works.

`'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I am on Windows 10.

Prior to installing Komodo, I was able to run python scripts from my command prompt.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

I uninstalled Komodo but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding path or system (windows only)

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
```

also you can try reinstalling the python and select add path to my system option on the bottom of the installer window.

Comment: can you add some screenshots of error for a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image: MyCommand Prompt]

@Ankit dagar Here is a screen shot of the Command Prompt An example of providing the full path to the executable program.

[image: Here is an exaple providing full path to the exec program]